# Intercept video tag src OTHER call and change the url from http to https?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I have passed **m3u8** file in video src tag for safari mobile browser. It is working fine and downloading all segments but in my case i have to change segment url from http to https how i can intercept video source call. is there any event which video tag used when it calls for source.

Comment: you're probably not going to be able to proxy it at the browser, so is there any way you can proxy and re-write the original manifest?

Comment: If you have control over the m3u8 file, it might be easier to edit the m3u8 to change source urls there